# Replacing a div with the contents of another div

Tags: jquery, css, html

I need to create a click event which replaces the contents of a specific div (#main_view) with the contents of a div(.clickContent) contained within a link. Here's the code:

```
<div id="main_view">Main View Target</div>

<ul class="webbies">
<li data-id="ab">
<a href="#"><img src="content/images/webby-andy-clarke.png" width="110" height="110" alt="" /></a>
<div class="clickContent">This is the click content</div>
</li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
$("ul.webbies li a").click(function() {
var content = $(this).html($('.clickContent').html());
$("#main_view").replace(content);
return false;       
});
</script>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to target the contents of the .clickContent div and then replace the main_view div.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is much simpler than you think:

```
$("ul.webbies li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main_view").html($('.clickContent').html());   
});
```

Now you might have to adjust the selectors if you have more than just one `.clickContent` div.

E.g. this would select the next sibling of the clicked link:

```
$("ul.webbies li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $(this).next('.clickContent').html();
    if(content) $("#main_view").html(content);
});
```

Also important to note is that you might break JavaScript if the copied content contains elements with IDs, as you then multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: better to change it to `function(e) { /* replace div */ e.preventDefault(); }` so bubbling still occurs and such

Comment: There will be multiple li items on the page. What's the best way to handle that? Using .closest??

Comment: @Jimmy: Done. @mmsa: Please see my update. It depends on the relationship between the link and the div. If the div always directly follows the link, then the second example will work.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use .text instead of .html if you wanted escape the html tags